# Is there a way to automatically export data from Excel?

Tags: excel

I have a worksheet that automatically gets updated with live stock price data.  At the moment we have a very messy solution of copying periodically to the clipboard and manipulating the data from there.

Is it possible to instead automatically export data to CSV every time a price change is detected? I'm guessing it would involve VBA.

Comment: Are the stock prices update via DDE?

Comment: I would be careful with having something dependent on "every price tick". Get yourself a busy stock or multiple stocks, suddenly your Excel application is constantly busy and unresponsive to user input. I'm not 100% sure whether Excel events catch the stock price updates (I can never remember if Bloomberg/Reuters play quite fair with the Excel platform) either. A periodic update is safest.

Answer (score 1):

You can treat excel file as a data source and you may query it.
See google results: http://www.google.ro/#sclient=psy&hl=ro&q=excel+data+source+sql+query&aq=0&aqi=g1&aql=&oq=&pbx=1&fp=b0efac6ab816e29b

I will try to find a specific article for you.

Comment: For example, try to access Excel through ODBC: http://www.oraxcel.com/projects/sqlxl/help/techniques/odbc_data_source_administrator/ . After you set up your data source, you just create a simple app/service that will query the xls data source using the convenient SQL language

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest the following strategy:

- Fire up your worksheet and switch into "design mode"
- Right-click the button which updates the stock info and try to find out to which macro the button is bound to
- Open the VBA editor (ALT+F11)
- Choose the "Workbook"-Section
- From there select the "Open" Event/Method
- Write a simple loop with a delay which calls the macro mentioned above periodically and programmatically save the excel-sheet as CSV

The code would be somthing like this (can't check it as I don't have access to excel right now):

```
Private Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)

Public Sub Workbook_open()
  Do While True

    Call name_of_macro()
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
    "c:\path/to/file.csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV _
    , CreateBackup:=False
    Sleep 10000 'Sleep 10 seconds

  Loop
End Sub
```

This example is just intended to show a rough solution. As Jean-Francois pointed out, this piece of code will NOT update everytime a change is detected, it will update every 10 seconds, even if the data is still the same.

Comment: Note that this will not "automatically export data to CSV every time a price change is detected" but rather every (10 seconds + `name_of_macro()` execution time) regardless of any price changes.

Comment: @Jean-Francois: True, I need to be a bit more precise. I just wanted to give deltanovember a pointer.

Comment: Fair enough, I just wanted @deltanovember to be aware

Answer (score 0):

This will do the trick:

```
Sub LoadNewValuesAndCheckForChange()

    Dim rngMyValues As Range
    Dim varBefore As Variant
    Dim varAfter As Variant
    Dim iRow As Long
    Dim iCol As Long
    Dim booValuesHaveChanged As Boolean

    Set rngMyValues = Range("B4:D9") ' Or wherever your data is

    varBefore = rngMyValues ' Save old values in an array

    ' Call the function that loads your new stock prices here...

    varAfter = rngMyValues ' Get new values

    ' Loop through all cells to see if anything has changed.
    booValuesHaveChanged = False
    For iRow = LBound(varBefore, 1) To UBound(varBefore, 1)
        For iCol = LBound(varBefore, 21) To UBound(varBefore, 21)
            If Not varAfter(iRow, iCol) = varBefore(iRow, iCol) Then
                ' Change detected!
                booValuesHaveChanged = True
            End If
        Next iCol
    Next iRow

    If booValuesHaveChanged Then
        ' Save .csv file with timestamp in filename
        ActiveWorksheet.SaveAs _
            Filename:="c:\myfile" & Format(Now, "yyyymmddhhnnss") & ".csv", _
            FileFormat:=xlCSV
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an Application.OnTime to set up a function to get called on a regular basis.

The following function gets called by Excel every 30 seconds. Either call it once to kick off the schedule or just set Application.OnTime once when your worksheet opens to get it running.

```
Public Sub DoExport()

    ' do your export to CSV logic here
    Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:30"), "DoExport"

End Sub
```